# Ergodicity and mixing

Tags: dynamical-systems, markov-chains

From [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74503/different-uses-of-the-word-ergodic/74505#74505), R W said:

> Unfortunately, the way the term "ergodic" is used in the theory of
>   (finite) Markov chains is completely misleading from the point of view
>   of general ergodic theory. To be consistent, one should have called
>   "ergodic" the chains whose state space does not admit a decomposition
>   into non-trivial non-communicating subsets. **The notion of ergodicity**
>   you are referring to would rather correspond to what is called
>   "mixing" in ergodic theory.

1. I wonder if **The notion of ergodicity** means the [ergodicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Ergodicity)
   concept for a Markov chain?
2. If yes, how does or is the [ergodicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Ergodicity) concept for a Markov
   chain correspond to or the same as "[mixing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_%28mathematics%29#Mixing_in_dynamical_systems)" in ergodic theory?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: The problem I see is, that you cannot have ergodic systems that are not mixing in a discrete case (ie markov chains). It is very well possible to differentiate between the two in general dynamical systems though.

Comment: ok, no. in markov chains ergodic systems actually might be decomposable... but then they are not mixing in the dynamical-system sense either...